# Getting a NaN error in Javascript Add function

Tags: javascript

Getting a NaN error in this addition function for script code, although there is no type conversion from string to int: Any suggestions?

```js
var add = function(a, b) {
  var i = 0,
    sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= arguments.length; i++) {
    sum += arguments[i];
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(add(10, 20, 30, 40, 50));
```

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: `arguments[arguments.length]` is undefined, consequently the final sum is not a number.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca arguments is just an internal object containing the arguments that are used inside the function

Comment: @Quentin you learn new things every day. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For loop condition part should be `i < arguments.length`

`arguments.length[arguments.length]` will be `undefined`

In the last iteration of the for loop, code was trying to add `150 + undefined` which resulted in `NaN`

Best way to figure out these type of problems is by debugging

Following are some debugging method

1. Use console statements and check what is happening
2. Use a debuggers and check line by line what is happening in your code

I personally use `node debugger`.

> You check line by line what is happening in your code and check values
>   of variable on the fly

Following is working code

```js
var add =  function (a,b) { 
 var i = 0,
      sum = 0;
  for (i = 0 ; i < arguments.length ; i ++) {
    sum += arguments[i];
  }
  return sum;
};

console.log(add(10,20,30,40,50));
```

Comment: Thanks suraj.tripathi for the Answer its working at my end now.

Comment: @VipinRamakrishnan accept the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the for loop's condition field incorrectly.

It should be:

```
(i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
```

(Notice the use of `<` instead of `<=`)

The problem is that you tried to add arguments[5] (because the length is 5, but arrays start at 0) which is undefined.

Number + undefined = NaN

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Markus-ivancsics its working now for me.